# Angular form not getting submitted with ng-submit

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. Just started my first demo project. The form is not getting submitted through the index.html. However if I try with the Template Html it submits the form. I have also tried with ng-click with submit button. Still it doesn't work. What am I missing here?

index.html

```html
<html ng-app="angularFormsApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/AngularFormsApp.js"></script>
    <script src="app/EmployeeForm/efController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/EmployeeForm/efDirective.js"></script>
    <script src="app/EmployeeForm/efService.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="efController" class="container">
    <employee-form/>
</body>
</html>
```

AngularFormsApp.js

```js
var angularFormsApp = angular.module('angularFormsApp', []);
```

efController.js

```js
angularFormsApp.controller('efController',

    function efController($scope, efService) {

        $scope.employee = efService.employee;

        $scope.departments = [
            "Engineering",
            "Marketing",
            "Finance",
            "Administration"];

        $scope.submitForm = function () {

        }
    });
```

efDirective.js

```js
angularFormsApp.directive('employeeForm',
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'app/EmployeeForm/efTemplate.html'
    }
  });
```

efService.js

```js
angularFormsApp.factory('efService',
  function() {
    return {
      employee: {
        fullName: "Wilton Adams",
        notes: "The ideal employee. Just don't touch his red stapler.",
        department: "Administration",
        perkCar: true,
        perkStock: false,
        perkSixWeeks: true,
        payrollType: "none"

      }
    }
  }
);
```

efTemplate.html

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="submitForm()">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Basic Information</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="fullName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullName" class="form-control" ng-model="employee.fullName" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="notes" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Notes</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <textarea name="notes" id="notes" class="form-control" rows="5" cols="40" ng-model="employee.notes"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="department" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Department</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select name="department" id="department" class="form-control" ng-model="employee.department" ng-options="dept for dept in departments"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <br />
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Perks</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">


        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="perkCar" ng-model="employee.perkCar" />Company Car
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="perkStock" ng-model="employee.perkStock" />Stock Options
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="perkSixWeeks" ng-model="employee.perkSixWeeks" />Six Weeks Vacation
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <br />
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Payroll Type</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">

        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="payrollType" value="w2" ng-model="employee.payrollType" />W-2
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="payrollType" value="ten99" ng-model="employee.payrollType" />1099
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="payrollType" value="none" ng-model="employee.payrollType" />None
          </label>
        </div>
        <br />

      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>


  <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now. Being the first app, i was trying to debug with toggle point. When I inserted an alert inside the submitForm() it showed the alert.It works with both the ng-click and ng-submit. Sometimes I can be too silly :D

Answer (score 0):

you should load efService.js before loading efController.js

```
<script src="app/AngularFormsApp.js"></script>
<script src="app/EmployeeForm/efService.js"></script>
<script src="app/EmployeeForm/efController.js"></script>
```